# Batch renaming files while asking user for name using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to batch rename files using Powershell. What I basically need is to:

```
$askUser = Read-Host 'What is the title'

$fpath = "path-to-files"
ForEach .mkv in $fpath{
    Rename-Item -NewName ($askUser + ".mkv")
}
```

If this makes any sense.

Comment: So... why don't you just do it?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with GigaRohan,

Look at the Following code to understand what you are missing, i've added comments

```
$askUser = Read-Host 'What is the title' ## For Example: Hello
$Counter = 1 ## This is a digit to add because you can't rename all the files to the same filename

$fpath = Get-ChildItem "C:\Test" -Include '*.mkv' -Recurse ## First get all your mkv files (filter only mkv files)
    ForEach ($mkv in $fpath) ## Start the loop
    {
        Rename-Item $mkv.FullName ("$askUser" + "_$Counter" + ".mkv") 

        ## rename the source file name which is $mkv.FullName (c:\test\file.mkv) to: 
        ## (everything in the parentheses will be the new name start with $askuser 
        ## then add _1 the adds .mkv for example "hello_1.mkv")

        $Counter ++ 
        ## add 1 to the counter digit so the next file will be "hello_2.mkv"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you should put in effort to find the solution to your problem and only if you can't or don't understand something, etc., should you post a question on SO.

For iterating files of a certain type in a directory (or in all sub-directories) and renaming them using PowerShell, see http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/11/22/use-powershell-to-rename-files-in-bulk.aspx

In your code, you change the name of all the .mkv files to the same. You can use `_<number>` at the end where `<number>` is an integer that is incremented for each additional file you rename in the loop.